# How to read Serial number from mobile device using C#?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, mobile, windows-ce

How I can read Serial number from a Windows mobile and WinCE mobile device using C#?

Answer (score 3):

You really shouldn't be using the old KernelIoControl method.

You should use the newer [GetDeviceUniqueID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms893522.aspx) API.  [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/windowsmobile/archive/2006/01/09/510997.aspx) is a blog entry on why to use it and how to use it from C#.

Answer (score 0):

[Retrieving the Windows CE Device ID with the Microsoft .NET Compact Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446562.aspx)

Comment: Interesting. I take that article to imply that some devices may not have a unique id. It seems to be something that "can be used by OEMs who need unique identifications". Also, the article was a bit old. Do you know if that IOCTL is still valid in later versions of Windows CE, or if maybe there's a better method in later versions?

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing built-in.  You must call native methods to get it - I have been away from the CompactFramework for a while though...

Comment: Right. I meant are there better native methods.